# Call WS Rest Java with AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

I've a problem with call WS Rest Java. I call the WS but the parameters isn't passed.

My java code:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response setUser(@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("surname") String surname, @FormParam("email") String email,
                        @FormParam("phone") String phone, @FormParam("skype") String skype, @FormParam("password") String password){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fis =  new FileOutputStream("/home/File.txt");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fis);
        String s = "name: "+name+"\nSurname: "+surname+"\nEmail: "+email+"\nPhone: "+phone+"\nSkype: "+skype+"\nPassword: "+password;
        ps.println(s);
        ps.close();
        fis.close();
        UserDAO userdao = new UserDAO(0,name,surname,email,phone,skype);
        userdao.save();
        ...
        return Response.status(200).entity(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("OK!")).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("ERROR!").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }
}
```

Angular call:

```
data = {
    name: $scope.reg_name,
    surname: $scope.reg_surname,
    email: $scope.reg_email,
    phone: $scope.reg_phone,
    skype: $scope.reg_skype,
    password: $scope.reg_password
  }
$http.post(baseUrl+'user/',data,{
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  });
```

If i log data on angular data are set, the call working but i've an error when i create AccountDAO object because the parameters are null. To test the parameters values i create a file and put here the value, the content are this:

> name: null
>
> Surname: null
>
> Email: null
>
> Phone: null
>
> Skype: null
>
> Password: null

Any one have idea why not pass the parameters?

Thanks!

Solved:

```
data = "name=" + $scope.reg_name +
"&surname=" + $scope.reg_surname +
"&email=" + $scope.reg_email +
"&phone=" + $scope.reg_phone +
"&skype=" + $scope.reg_skype +
"&password=" + $scope.reg_password;
  }
$http.post(baseUrl+'user/',data,{
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  })
```

Thanks grizzly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending data as JSON. Change it to form data string:

```
  data = "name=" + $scope.reg_name +
    "&surname=" + $scope.reg_surname +
    "&email=" + $scope.reg_email +
    "&phone=" + $scope.reg_phone +
    "&skype=" + $scope.reg_skype +
    "&password=" + $scope.reg_password;
  }
$http.post(baseUrl+'user/',data,{
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  })
```